# Validate in conflict with "action" code in the form

Tags: php, javascript

I have a input text area where i want the user to enter his FULL name. So it's obligatory to have at least two word in the field.

But the validate code it's in conflict with the action code (action="nome.php") of the form.

How do i fix that?

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
function validateMe(form_elm)
{
var full = form_elm.user.value;
// clear any spaces in front
while (full.charAt(0) == " ") full = full.substr(1);
// split and check for two names - dual purpose of also retrieving first and last name for future use
full = full.split(" ");
var first_name = full[0];
var last_name = full[1];
if (full.length < 2) alert("Please enter your full name.");
return false;
}
// ]]>
</script>

<form method="post" name="input" action="nome.php" onsubmit="return validateMe(this)">
Fazer reserva em nome de:
<input name="user" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="NEXT" />
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to have the `return` in `return validateMe(this)`

Comment: without the `return` in `return validateMe(this)` the message shows but the action is executed! I want the action to be executed ONLY if the message is NOT shown.

Comment: @FelipeGrinsztajn I suggest you scrap your Javascript validation and use server-side PHP instead. If the user has JS disabled, then yours will ultimately fail, unless you have a `<noscript></noscript>` option. I deleted my question because I felt it was not worth putting the effort into, because of just that, JS validation. It's not worth it. Do as I suggest, you will thank me for it. Cheers

Comment: Client-side validation is good UI. It's not "real" validation. Just a convenience, and a good one. Of course you do the real validation on the server.

Comment: @Jeffman I rarely have JS enabled and for so many reasons. I don't know them from "Adam", so I'm not about to trust any Web site, just because they have some cool graphics and what not. So IMO, JS validation should only be used as "icing on the cake", as it were, while using PHP validation as a "sure fire" method. There is just way too many malicious intent out there for my taste.

Comment: It's great that you agree with me, then, Fred. o.O

Comment: @Jeffman Indeed I do. *Peace*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try trimming the whitespace from the ends of the value of the full name field, and then splitting it and checking the length of the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/bBZry/

```
function validate(el) {
    var text = el.user.value.trim();
    console.log(text);
    var words = text.split(" ");
    if (words.length > 1) {
     return true;   
    } else {
     return false;   
    }
}

if (!String.prototype.trim){
    String.prototype.trim = function(){
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    }
}
```